# A Duplicate? Seriously?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

@Mark Trapp marked:

- [what do i need to learn in order to get an entry level asp.net job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111881/what-do-i-need-to-learn-in-order-to-get-an-entry-level-asp-net-job)

  as a duplicate of
- [If you develop with ASP.NET, which other technologies do you use?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66389/if-you-develop-with-asp-net-which-other-technologies-do-you-use)

These questions aren't even close!
They're asking two completely different things!

**EDIT:**
Q: What do i need to learn in order to get an entry level asp.net job?
A: You need to learn how to create CRUD pages and you need to learn SQL.

Q: If you develop with ASP.NET, which other technologies do you use?
A: I use a hodgepodge of complimentary technologies. I use technology X, technology Y, etc..., NHibernate, and Entity Framework.

Both answers are perfectly valid answers to their respective questions.
Neither answer is a good answer to the opposite question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct.  It is clear that "what do i need to learn in order to get an entry level asp.net job?" is broader than "If you develop with ASP.NET, which other technologies do you use?" despite being able to pick out overlap in the body, and could reasonably be expected to get different answers.

Answer (score 10):

First question:

> I wanted to know how much C#, SQL, CSS, XHTML, Javascript and/or jQuery I need to learn in order to have a chance of getting an entry level ASP.NET job.

Second question:

> I'm a Microsoft developer, so I'm going to use ASP.NET. I'm familiar with how the web technologies work at a high level, I sort of understand what Javascript can do, I get AJAX (conceptually). CSS and HTML seem ugly but I get what they're for.
>
> As an ASP.NET developer do you find yourself working directly with Javascript or HTML? Does AJAX get abstracted away neatly or do you find yourself doing that stuff "by hand"? Are there any other technologies you use?

They're asking exactly the same thing: getting into ASP.NET, need to know what other technologies you need to know to do it properly.

If they aren't asking the same, I suggest revising the question—with the original poster's consent—to ask something besides "What other things do I need to know to do ASP.NET?"